# Can I have different form_loads inside a form that can be assigned to a specific event/action? C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, button

I'm making a windows form app and I have one form that represents a base form and it gets data  from a different class (that's almost like a database):

```
private void base_form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database_class dc = new database_class();
        button1.Text =dc.Name;
    }
```

NOTE: The reason why this code is in the form_Load is because it doesn't show up, unless I put it there, which I find strange, but it might not be?

I have a main form, that acts like a menu - it has four buttons on it and all the buttons lead to the base form. The database class is actually supposed to change the names of the controls in the base form based on the what button is chosen in the main form(menu). The base form has a lot more buttons than the main form.

Since this is confusing, here's an example of what I want to do: If the menu had options (buttons) Mozart, Beethoven, Liszt, Chopin - when people click on Mozart they're supposed to get buttons with the names of his compositions, if they click Beethoven then they get his compositions and so on.(These buttons in the base form do lead to something else, if that's important/helpful). The reason I'm not making separate forms for these menu buttons, is because I have a lot of buttons and I don't think making plenty of forms is ideal (it's a simple app, I don't want to slow it down with a lot of forms).

My question is what is the best way to do this? Do I have to somehow assign the data I want to the button (mouse) click events in the menu (main form)? Is there a possibility of having different form loads in the base form, that can be assigned to the mouse clicks in the menu?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why do you think having lots of forms in an application will slow it down ?

Comment: @GuidoG It actually happened before, I had an app that had a lot of forms and it was struggling. However, this app if I were to make separate forms, would have 200 forms that are very similar to each other, so I'm trying to reduce the number with inheritance and databases, and different information within the base form loading based on the buttons that are chosen is going to be a big part of the app, unless there is a better way to do it and I'm unaware?

Comment: my current winform application has about 150 forms, it does not slows it down. There must be another reason for that, maybe you load all your forms when starting the app and never dispose them ? If your forms are very similar then visual inheritance is the way to go. That is how I am doing it

Comment: @GuidoG Good point, I'll try that out. Thank you.

Comment: You can add arguments to the sub-form's constructor to pass context.

Comment: @peeebeee Could you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Example constructor as requested - form has a `richTextBox` that gets populated by the constructor and also a `string` value that's used later:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string _filename;

    public Form2(string text, string filename)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
        _filename = filename;
    }
}
```

Create an instance of this form from the main form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string textForRTB = "Some text";
      string valueForFilename = "\some\file\name";  
      Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textForRTB, valueForFilename);
      frm2.Show();
    }
```